# Proper placement of thermostat

Tags: thermostat, placement

I am building a new home and the question of where the thermostat for the upstairs should go has risen. It was originally wired to be place in my daughter's bedroom but I had requested that it be moved to the hallway at the top of the stairs.  The home is approx. 4300 sq ft with about 700 sq ft being a mother'n'law suite.  So there is one thermostat downstairs in the family room, one in the inlaw suite and one upstairs.  There is 2 ac units and we are on a dual zone system.  The supervisor of the job said that it would be fine to move it and the inspector I hired to go through pre dry wall orientation said it should be in one of the upstairs bedrooms.  There are 2 bedrooms/ each with their own baths, a small laundry room and a storage closet upstairs.  Not sure where the best location for the thermostat is?

Comment: Do you want bedroom doors to be open or closed at night?

Comment: I would think they would be open at night.

Comment: I vote for the hall way.  There, it well best sense the temperature of the overall general vicinity. With the bedroom door closed the stat will be isolated for the upstairs area.

Comment: If you locate it too close to the top of the stairs, it could be influenced by the heat rising up the stairway.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question, without knowing a lot more about the building.  There are a lot of factors that go into thermostat placement, and you have not supplied enough information for anybody to provide a short, simple answer. If remote sensors are an option in your situation, that would likely be the most accurate way to balance the temperature in the space.

Answer (score 1):

The thermostat is what senses the temperature so you want it where you want the most accurate temperature which would be in the bedroom however all other rooms will be a little off. The hallway may provide a good mix of temperatures or all the rooms may be hotter or colder than the hall. I have been using the Honeywell 8000 series thermostat with remote sensors and getting good results. You can add up to 6 sensors and they will all average. Put the thermostat in the hall for easy access and install wireless sensors in the bedrooms. There are of course other brands with remote sensors, I am just not to familiar with them.